# Type-safe formatted output in Scala

Tags: scala, printf

I am thinking if it is possible to implement a type-safe `printf` in Scala. Suppose we need to support only *string literals*, *%s*, and *%d*

I would like `printf("This is number %d", 0)` to be compiled but `printf("This is number %d", "abc")` not to be.

I would like `printf` to check the number of arguments in compile-time. So `printf("This is a literal")` would be compiled but `printf("This is number %d and string %s", 0)` would not.

I have seen it can be done with macros. Are macros absolutely necessary to implement type-safe `printf` ?

Comment: I don't see how it could be done. Without macros a string is just a string. Maybe if you change `"number %d"` to `"number ".%d`.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I should have written that I am thinking about a printf-like mini-DSL rather than the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt to implement such a thing without macros. There might be a less ugly way... And some extra methods should be added to make it more convenient.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

package test {

  sealed trait End
  sealed trait Prove[T]
  object Prove{
      implicit object EndProve extends Prove[F[End,End]]
  }

  class F[A,B](ss: List[String]){
    def _d(s: String) = new F[Int,F[A,B]](s :: ss)
    def _s(s: String) = new F[String,F[A,B]](s :: ss)
  }

}

package object test {

  implicit def string2F(s: String) = new F[End,End](List(s))


  def printf[A,B](a: A)(f: F[A,B])(implicit ev: Prove[B]) = ???

  def printf[A,B,C](b: B, a: A)(f: F[A,F[B,C]])(implicit ev: Prove[C]) = ???

  def printf[A,B,C,D](c: C, b: B, a: A)(f: F[A,F[B,F[C,D]]])(implicit ev: Prove[D]) = ???

  // and so on...
}
```

As you can see it does work (if you implement the actual printing):

```
scala> import test._
import test._

scala> printf(4, "string")("a digit: " _d " and a String: " _s ".") // compiles
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

scala> printf(4, 6)("a digit: " _d " and a String: " _s ".") // doesn't compile
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;

scala> printf(4)("a digit: " _d " and a String: " _s ".")  // doesn't compile
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
```

Answer (score 5):

Scala's `f` string formatter is already a typesafe `printf`. It is implemented using a macro. Example:

```
scala> val s = "not a number"
s: String = not a number

scala> f"$s%d"
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
              f"$s%d"
                 ^
```

Comment: This really seems more like a comment—it doesn't really try to answer the question.